# Spring WebServiceTemplate incorrectly using Xerces to unmarshal XML response

Tags: cxf, spring-ws, xerces, maven-jaxb2-plugin

i'm working with Spring WST and consuming a WCF SOAP 1.1 web service. I've used Apache's CXF Maven plugin to generate the web service client from the WSDL. When i inspect the generated classes it looks as JAXB has been used and everything is as expected at this point.

However when i send a request to the web service (via Spring WST) the response object is using  the Xerces ElementNSImpl to represent the response.

Here is an example of whats happening;

1. Apache CXF generates object names PersonResponseObject, PersonRequestObject
2. I populate the PersonRequestObject and submit with the help of Spring WST
3. The WCF service returns the content as expected (i can print the SOAP response to console) however during the unmarshal the PersonResponseObject is injected with the ElementNSImpl type which is a Xerces type.

It seems to me that i need to explicitly force the use of JAXB during the unmarshal process however I'm not sure if this is something i need to tell the Spring tenplate or somewhere else.

Anyone familiar with this problem and have any suggestions?
Sample of the returned XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PersonResponseObject xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <PersonResponseObjectResult>
    <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="NewDataSet">
      <xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" name="NewDataSet">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="Table">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ActivityName" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ActivityDesc" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Activityid" type="xs:int" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Status" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PlanDate" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Duedate" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsRequired" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReqStatus" type="xs:int" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
      <NewDataSet xmlns="">
```

Comment: Probably a namespace problem or something similar. Can you post some of the returned XML, and the `PersonResponseObject` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a crazy mixed-up bit of XML. It returns some XML, with a schema nested inside. That means the XML content is dynamic, probably (googling Diffgram looks like it returns arbitrary relational database data). I doubt you're going to have a lot of luck using JAXB out-of-the-box. At the very least, you need to save some the returned schemas to XML files and then generate new JAXB objects for them.

Comment: so while this didnt really answer the question exactly it got me on the right track. the wsdl was generating the class however the content inside the class was just raw xml.. it is a mess :)